# read UDPv4: Connection reset by peer (WSAECONNRESET) (fd=240,code=10054)

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, openvpn

go t  my server up and when loading client get this error. thank you for any help!

server config

port 1194

proto udp

dev tun
auth-nocache

ca "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\easy-rsa\pki\ca.crt"

cert "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\easy-rsa\pki\issued\server.crt"

key "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\easy-rsa\pki\private\server.key"

dh "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\easy-rsa\pki\dh.pem"

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

keepalive 10 120

## tls-auth "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\easy-rsa\ta.key" 0 # This file is secret

cipher AES-256-CBC
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC

## data-ciphers cipher AES-256-CBC

persist-key

persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3

explicit-exit-notify 1

client config

client
dev tun
;dev-node MyTap
;proto tcp
proto udp
remote 174.141.223.114 1194
;remote my-server-2 1194
;remote-random
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
;user nobody
;group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
;http-proxy-retry # retry on connection failures
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port #]
;mute-replay-warnings
remote-cert-tls server
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
;mute 20

log file on startup

MANAGEMENT: CMD 'signal SIGHUP'
2022-12-15 13:33:04 SIGHUP[hard,init_instance] received, process restarting
2022-12-15 13:33:04 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1671129184,RECONNECTING,init_instance,,,,,
2022-12-15 13:33:04 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2022-12-15 13:33:04 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'BF-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). OpenVPN ignores --cipher for cipher negotiations.
2022-12-15 13:33:04 Note: '--allow-compression' is not set to 'no', disabling data channel offload.
2022-12-15 13:33:04 OpenVPN 2.6_beta1 [git:release/2.6/e778a6fd26d849dc] Windows-MSVC [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] [DCO] built on Dec  2 2022
2022-12-15 13:33:04 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7), amd64 executable
2022-12-15 13:33:04 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022, LZO 2.10
2022-12-15 13:33:04 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
2022-12-15 13:33:09 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2022-12-15 13:33:09 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
2022-12-15 13:33:09 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]174.141.223.114:1194
2022-12-15 13:33:09 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
2022-12-15 13:33:09 UDPv4 link local: (not bound)
2022-12-15 13:33:09 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]174.141.223.114:1194
2022-12-15 13:33:09 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1671129189,WAIT,,,,,,
2022-12-15 13:33:09 read UDPv4: Connection reset by peer (WSAECONNRESET) (fd=240,code=10054)
2022-12-15 13:33:11 read UDPv4: Connection reset by peer (WSAECONNRESET) (fd=240,code=10054)
2022-12-15 13:33:15 read UDPv4: Connection reset by peer (WSAECONNRESET) (fd=240,code=10054)

many thanks

followed the openvpn documentation, bit confusing